# How to use ng-grid of Angular JS for varying JSON data?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a JSON data. Simplified example:

```
 [{"name":"xxx","age":23},{"name":"yyy","age":25}]
```

**Data can vary (even keys can be different).**

I want to show this as a table on UI using AngularJs. I am a new to Angular world. I am using ng-grid for this.

In my JS file :

```
        //queryResponse is having above mentioned JSON data.

            $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'queryResponse',
            rowHeight:46,
            headerRowHeight:40,
            enablePaging: false,
            showFooter: false,
            enableRowSelection: false,
            columnDefs: [....]       
            };
```

What should be there in `columnDefs` as I can't hard code`displayName`, it should be taken from keys of JSON data like `name` & `age` for above mentioned code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove columnDefs property from gridoptions and will display your key's as heading. Include columnDefs with displayName only if you want to display a static heading for specified key

Comment: it works but when data changes it does not change the header

Comment: @dev if you could post your changed data then we can see why & where its going wrong